# .NET Core API: PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-5

**Background:**

I am just starting out with Azure CosmosDB and trying to make use of the Entity Framework CosmosDB provider. I have created a simple API, along with Swagger API documentation, which will operate on a single entity.

So far I have done the following:

1. Configured a new Cosmos DB database + container
2. Registered CosmosDB into the services container in Startup.cs
3. Configured an entity that I want to store in my new Cosmos DB container
4. Prepared API endpoints for basic CRUD operations

**Problem:**

When attempting to call my POST endpoint through Swagger to create a new record in my database, I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 1001; ActivityId: fe27e816-173c-433e-8699-e9e49e01b96f; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"]}

From following tutorials and documentation, it's not obvious why I am getting this error! Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

**Potentially useful snippets that might help someone diagnose where I am going wrong:**

**Registering Cosmos DB to the service container:**

```cs
var settings = new CosmosDbOptions();

configuration.GetSection(CosmosDbOptions.SECTION_NAME)
    .Bind(settings);

services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => 
    {
        options.UseCosmos(
            accountEndpoint: settings.EndpointUri,
            accountKey: settings.PrimaryKey,
            databaseName: settings.DatabaseName
        );
    });
```

**Entity:**

```cs
public class Client : Entity, IGuidIdentifier, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Client() : base() 
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.ClientId = this.Id.ToString();
    }

    public string ClientId { get; private set; }

    public IrisCode IrisCode { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Office Office { get; private set; }

    public Logo Logo { get; private set; }
}
```

**Entity framework confgiguration for my entity:**

```cs
public class ClientConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Client> builder)
    {
        builder.ToContainer("Clients");
        builder.HasPartitionKey(x => x.ClientId);

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Name);
        builder.Property(x => x.ClientId);
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.IrisCode);
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Office);
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Logo);

        builder.Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);
    }
}
```

Update: It seems that the following line is causing the error, however, this leaves me in a position without having my desired partition key defined..

```cs
builder.HasPartitionKey(x => x.ClientId);
```

Comment: How are you writing records? Apparently it looks like you are creating a container with /ClientId as Partition Key. Are you passing the value of the ClientId property as PartitionKey when you insert the records?

Comment: I am writing the records using standard EF appraoch: 1. Create an entity (the `ClientId`  property is being set in the constructor so it defo has a value) 2. `context.Clients.Add(client)`

Comment: So it seems that this line in the entity configuration: `builder.HasPartitionKey(x => x.ClientId);` was causing the problem. I remove this, and it works! However, I no longer have the desired partition key... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error `(PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header)` is coming because the partition key which you have set for your Cosmos DB collection is different from what you are setting here in EF: `ClientId`.

Pls make sure that you have the same partition key for your Collection, for eg., you can set it using C# like below:

```
this.Container = await this.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("testContainer", "/clientId");
```

and have the key in your document object like below:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientId")]
public string ClientId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. issue was with the camel casing of properties. Fixed it using this code:

```
 CosmosSerializationOptions cosmosSerializationOptions = new()
 {
     PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
     IgnoreNullValues = true
 };

 cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(
      settings.CosmosDbConnectionString,
      new CosmosClientOptions()
      {
          ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
          SerializerOptions = cosmosSerializationOptions,
          AllowBulkExecution = true
      });
```